List button with Visualforce page on related list
I am trying to build a custom solution wherein I have a custom list button to be shown on related list of OpportunityLineItem. The list button is on standard object OpportunityLineItemSchedule which is a child of OpportunityLineItem.
Through this button I am trying to achieve Scheduling custom field. As in standard we can schedule standard fields like Revenue.
So through list button I am trying to open VF page. That again has LWC connected.

I have used recordSetVar here but it says List controller is not
allowed on OpportunityLineItemSchedule Object.

How can I use list button in Schedules object to achieve this functionality. This is where the button will come:

<apex:page standardController="OpportunityLineItemSchedule" extensions="scheduleManhoursController">
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="LwcId"> </div>
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:scheduleManhoursApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:scheduleManhours",
    {
        recordId : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}'
    },
    "LwcId", // the Id of div tag where component will be rendered
    function(cmp) {
        console.log('Calling the LWC Component');
    });
});
</script>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class scheduleManhoursController {

    public scheduleManhoursController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        
    }
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static list<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> getSchedulesByBidService(id bidServiceId) {

        return [SELECT OpportunityLineItem.Name,ScheduleDate,Total_Manhours__c,Percentage__c,Description FROM 
        OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId = :bidServiceId];

    }
}

